# Persisting state for singleton WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf

I have a singleton WCF service hosted in IIS. I want to implement a store for persisting state for the service. I am writing my data to XML file.

Can you please tell me what is the recommended way of doing this? What events I can listen to while my WCF service unloads and reloads.

Comment: What kind of state do you want to save? Why do you have stateful / singleton service?

Comment: my service is a scheduler that has multiple timer instances. I am trying to know the behavior of the service when IIS restarts or host computer restarts or AppDomain reloads. I will need  to persist state Correct?? I would like to recreate timers based on my stored state. Thanks.

Comment: What are your real requirements ? So far, it doesn't sound like a singleton is a good approach, so asking the recommended way of persisting singleton state is not going to get you the best end result.

Comment: I want the timer configurations, service state to be persisted. I think Durable service can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment the only valid approach is persisting service state each time the configuration changes - it means in each request changing the setting. Otherwise after each unexpected termination of the AppDomain you will lose last configuration.

Comment: Exactly. Durable WCF services will be helpful?

Comment: I think durable WCF service is service using workflow persistence facility to store itself to database. It is supposed to be used when many instances can exist. It is too much for your scenario where you have single service instance.